# Why won't the python module keyboard type and Say something in Roblox?

Tags: python, keyboard, roblox

This is in python for Roblox by the way.

`Command["text"] = input("Say what? ")`

And then later in the code...

By the way, LoopCommand is the same as Command.

```
                    text = LoopCommand["text"]
                    keyboard.press('/')
                    time.sleep(0.04)
                    keyboard.release("/")
                    keyboard.write(text)
                    keyboard.press("Enter")
                    keyboard.release("Enter")
```

Basically this code is meant to take text the user gives it and automatically say it in Roblox. Although, when In Roblox, the chat window just opens as if / was pressed but then immediately enter was pressed.